# Change small_image size Magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I need to change the small image size on Magento community.
Here´s why, it does not fit the global product window.
[link here](http://shop.lopezi.com/index.php/dubai.html)

I tried at \app\design\frontend\default\magik_pinstyle\template\catalog\product\list.phtml
and flushed the image cache but I does not work.

I can see it`s a 265px image but when I search for a resize(265) I dont find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would actually be located in `app/design/frontend/default/magik_pinstyle/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml`. Copy the file over from `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml` if you don't have it on your template. On line 68 (in the base media.phtml) you'll find this line:

```
$_img = '<img src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(265).'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" itemprop="image" />';
```

Your photos don't fit the frame because your `.product-view .product-img-box .product-image` CSS is set to 320x300px (width/height). If you want your pictures to fit, you need to make sure the resize is set to the same size of the frame, and you should probably square off your frame.

- If you want the larger frame, change your image CSS to 320x320px or 300x300px and change the above line to `resize(320)` or `resize(300)`, respectively.
- If you want to keep the 265x265px image size, change your image CSS to 265x265px and leave it as is.

**Edit**

It is still using a file in 265x265px resize cache.

You should deliberately clear out everything in your `/media/catalog/product/cache` folder, first the media.phtml checks to see if a resize already exists and falls back to that. If one isn't found, then it runs the resize.

You are editing the file found in `app/design/frontend/default/magik_pinstyle/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml`, correct? If altering the existing resize function doesn't work after completely emptying the cache you can add the `->resize(300)` function to line 15:

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(300)
```

Lastly, if you have a custom lightbox or theme section in your settings, check for anything you may have missed to alternately set dimensions.

Make sure to refresh your cache, you should clear your image cache too.

Comment: Check my edits. Your CSS and resize do not match. That is why it doesn't fit.

Comment: for moments I was hoping that would work but it does not. I resize(300) at media.html, the code was already there. furthermore I had put width and height to 300px also like you suggested. it`s odd cause the image is still 265px and I do not have that size in any part of the code. yes, it looks like cache but i cleaned it up a couple a times.

Comment: Did you also click "Flush Catalog Images Cache" on the Cache Management screen?

Comment: yes, I even went to the image folder on the server and remove the image itself. It loads a new one, 265px. There must be another place where the image is being generated other than media.phtml. Any idea where?

Comment: Check my edits and see if any of those solutions work for you. You may want to go directly into your media/catalog/product/cache folder and delete everything in there, if it's not emptying after clearing Magento image cache.

Comment: it was the lightbox @Jason. never helps when you search the answer on the wrong site. thank you

Comment: Awesome! Quite a checklist you have to go through, right? Keep up on being as knowledgeable as you can on the Magento structure. It's quite a maze at first, but after you get the idea you can take on any MVC (Model-View-Controller) app you come across.

Comment: I think I have the same problem, but I don't understand the solution you came across with the lightbox / template -  where should I check for this? I've asked a question on it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19414881/1814446)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old post but but I want to add something that seems to be left out off most of these responses, you must enlarge the container that the image is contained in otherwise the image will not be enlarged.

I followed the first part of Jason's answer above by going into

```
app/design/frontend/default/magik_pinstyle/template/catalog/ 
/view/media.phtml. Copy the file over from app/design/frontend
/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtm
```

and changing line 32 and 33 to

```
$bigImageX  = 608;   from $bigImageX  = 308;
$bigImageY = 608;    from $bigImageY = 308;
```

and nothing happened after flushing of the cache both magento nor browswer.

I then went into dev tools and enlarged the `width` of

```
<div class="produt-img-box">
```

which increased the size of the image to my desired size. 
Just to be clear, I also had to shrink the size of the 
`<div class="product-shop">` to totally accomplish my goal of resizing the image.